# Removing Blank Lines in Log

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

In GF 3.1.x, the logs that are echoed to the screen in Netbeans have blank lines.  Is there any way to remove the blank, so there is less to scroll through?  I know this is minor, but anything to make the day more productive....

```
INFO: 08:40:33,170  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:186 - Mapped "{[/search],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" 

INFO: 08:40:33,171  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:186 - Mapped "{[/search],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}"
```

Comment: http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/21123-remove-blank-lines.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$ sed '/^$/d' blanks.txt > without_blanks.txt`